# Turn Background White Without Selecting Each Individual Area in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, interface-design, prototyping

I have these low-fi prototypes, which I've drawn with pen on computer paper. After scanning them, though, the computer paper is not quite #FFFFFF [image]

Is there a quick way to make the background as close to white as possible in Photoshop? Without selecting each individual area around the pen lines and brightening them 1 by 1? I already tried increasing the contrast. Ultimately, I'd like to insert these scans into a Design Process document, so I'd like for them to look as clean as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can whiten the light parts (and even darken the dark parts) with a Curves Adjustment Layer. Go to Layer> New Adjustment Layer> Curves. The curve will have a diagonal line from upper right to lower left. Click on the line and drag up and / or down as shown in the picture below.

The same is also possible with a Levels adjustment Layer- basically making the lights whiter and the darks blacker. You have much more control with either of these compared to a Contrast Adjustment.
[image]

My first hit was to re-draw it in any vector drawing program. But now I am thinking that you probably want this hand drawn look.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very quick method using a Levels adjustment

Hit the "highlight" eyedropper tool in the Levels dialog, and click on the area that is supposed to be white.

[image]